# How to fix double- (triple, quadruple...) counted pages in Google Analytics for previous months?

Tags: google-analytics

I have several months worth of data in Google Analytics that is currently more or less useless, because some pageviews were being counted 2 or 3 (or more?) times.

[image: See here]

The issue as far as I can tell came from a combination of a jQuery address plugin and AddThis' adding a tracking # to URLs shared on social media.

I've removed the plugins and implemented [this filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4vks.png) to stop Google Analytics from tracking trailing vs. non-trailing slashes as 2 or more pageviews.

It works now, but is there a good way to go back and apply the filter to previous months? 
[image]

The data *should* be salvageable I think, since Analytics tracked the Sessions correctly, but the Pageviews and Unique Pageviews way too high.

[image]

[image]

Comparing an affected time period last year to the same (unaffected) time period this year:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately... Once GA data is sent and processed on their servers, it can't be changed.

Although your "pages/session" and "bounce rate" are unreliable, most of the other information should still be fine, for example "device type". Even conversion rate percentages are calculated as Conversions / Users - so in most cases that won't be affected.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to set up a filtered view / segment that would fix it? So I wouldn't be editing the data, just how I see it.